# 50-60 gb of data in spark standalone mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, machine-learning, statistics, bigdata

I am trying to analyze around 50-60 gb of data. I thought of using spark to do that, but I do not have access to multiple nodes in a cluster. Can this level of processing be done using spark standalone mode ? If yes, I would like to know the estimated time required to process the data.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes.

Spark will partition this file in many smaller chunks. In your case only few chunks will be executed at a time. These few chunks should fit in memory (you need to play with the configurations to get this right)

To summarize, you will be able to do it, but it would be faster if you had more memory/cores so you can processes more things in parallel.

Comment: I have a macbook pro with i7 processor, 16 GB RAM . How much time do you think it would take ?